# Is it a good way to draw Candle graph using open flash chart?

Tags: flash, charts, real-time

I want to draw stock price in real time as a candle graph. I get open flash chart from someone and it looks good at drawing. I don't know how to update the candle graph in real time (using Ajax?), and is it a good way?

I use Python a lot. But I cannot find tools as easily to use as OFC.

Answer (score 1):

I would move away from Flash if you can (I am a flash developer). Try a Javascript Library like which will work on things like the iPhone, iPad, Macbook Air. HTML5 devices.
http://raphaeljs.com/

Some simple charts here 
http://raphaeljs.com/chart.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jqplot.com/ should be great solution for you

Answer (score 0):

In Open Flash Chart there is a candle.txt file that is the template for just this kind of chart.

Open Flash Chart Rules! (and I dislike Flash)

```
{
  "title":{
    "text":  "Candle",
    "style": "{font-size: 20px; color:#0000ff; font-family: Verdana; text-align: center;}"
  },
  "y_legend":{
    "text": "Open Flash Chart",
    "style": "{color: #736AFF; font-size: 12px;}"
  },
  "elements":[
    {
      "type":      "candle",
      "alpha":     0.5,
      "colour":    "#40d040",
      "negative-colour":    "#d04040",
      "text":      "Burn baby, burn",
      "font-size": 10,
      "on-show":    {"type": "po-p", "cascade":1, "delay":0},
      "tip":       "#x_label#<br>High: #high#<br>Open: #open#<br>Close: #close#<br>Low: #low#",
      "values" :   [
        {"high":19, "top":14, "bottom":11, "low":10, "tip":"LOOK<br>#top#,#bottom# = #val#"},
        {"high":15, "top":10, "bottom":5, "low":0},
        {"high":7, "top":7, "bottom":4, "low":3},
        {"high":7, "top":3, "bottom":6, "low":2},
        {"high":7, "top":4, "bottom":4, "low":2}
        ]
    }
  ],
  "x_axis":{
    "labels": ["January","February","March"]
   },
  "y_axis":{
    "max": 20
  }
}
```